# Is " $(document).ready(function () " required for AJAX generated JS?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ready

Please answer this question as I have failed to get proper understanding of the issue and simply cannot locate any material to read on it.
The question, generically speaking, requires the consideration of the following commonly used structure. Yes, the JS may go at the bottom but that's a different discussion.

```
    <html>
     ...
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
          ....  //Script to be used in this document
        });
    </script>
       ...more html
    <div id="ajax_div" ... > 
      <script>
         **$(document).ready(function ()** { //2nd wrapper
            ....
          });
      </script>
         ... AJAX returned HTML
    </div>
```

The question: Is the second wrapper required to be generated in the AJAX response? I understand that document.ready makes sure that the DOM is ready before the JS can work on it. Should the same logic, then, not apply to AJAX generated JS? Are there cases when it is required and when it is not required?   I had a situation where the wrapper on-document-ready for AJAX generated JS fixed something but all along I have not been using it for other situations and all was well!!!

Hope its not a dumb question! If it is a repeat, please refer me to it. I could not locate any...

Comment: No, `$(document).ready` is never *required*, it's just a tool that you can use to cause your code execution to be delayed until the DOM is ready. In your case, you're firing off an ajax request after the dom is ready, meaning your response will also be received after the dom is ready. Therefore, you don't need to wait for the dom to be ready again because you already know it is ready.

Comment: personally, I'd keep the DOMReady wrapper; make things consistent and uniform so in the event of a non-ajax reference, you're not in trouble. jQuery just fast-forwards DOMReady calls assigned after ready-state anyways, so it's just one additional hope (relatively low overhead all things considered).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What if the AJAX-generated JS needs elements in the AJAX-generated HTML generated from the Ajax itself. In that case would it not be mandatory to have the AJAX JS wait for these elements to be "ready" in the DOM? I have some pretty complicated, relatively speaking, AJAX-generated JS,  that .prepends, appends, etc. new elements to the AJAX-generated HTML. It fails consistently unless I use the $(document).ready. I got the fix but I need to understand why. Your explanation helps but some more elaboration on the exact scenario described here will help.

Comment: Nope, you should not use $(document).ready() for that. In any case, that event will not fire again. You need to use the promise objects returned by the AJAX calls and bind the execution of success of one AJAX call to the promise of another one being fulfilled.

Comment: @Chandranshu, the event does fire again. As for promises, I do use them but did not want to complicate my question by mentioning them. I have not explored using promises within promises. Perhaps my lack of understanding is at a more basic level. When an AJAX call returns HTML, does it not actually change the DOM even at the most basic level? After all you are inserting, in most cases, some nested elements inside some existing element. No matter what, is it not necessary, at least in theory, to wait for the DOM to be updated for any AJAX generated JS to work on it?

Comment: Strictly in theory, it is not necessary to wait for the DOM to be updated for any AJAX generate JS to work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following scenario:

1. You loaded a page in browser. The browser had to load some included javascript which was parsed as it was loaded.
2. While the page was still loading:

   1. the parsed JS sent an AJAX request.
   2. the server sent back a response text
   3. The success() handler of the AJAX call wants to add the returned text into a div which is not yet loaded.
   4. error
3. Document ready event triggers as document finishes loading.

Now, in step 2.3, it may happen that the returned code or the success/failure callbacks were capable of working with the partially loaded document since their targets were already loaded at that point of time. You'll then not notice any errors.

On the other hand, if the AJAX call itself is fired after the document is ready, then your generated JS doesn't have to wrap itself in a `document.ready` block.

Comment: thanks. Can you refer to my comments above? I presume what you are saying is that YES it is important not just recommended to have the AJAX code wrapped in the document.ready block for the scenario I have. Am I correct?

Comment: Just the calling code i.e. your $.ajax() call. After that whatever the server returns will execute just fine.

Comment: As @Brad Christie pointed out, "in the event of non-ajax reference" I got that part. That refers to the AJAx js, referring to the outer HTML in the main document which has failed to load. You appear to be referring to that same scenario. My question is the inner HTML returned by AJAX. It too needs to get "ready" to be accessed by the JS.  If it makes a "ajax reference" and not the "non-Ajax reference" which is explained well by Brad.